# How can you hide html element with php?

Tags: php

if you do in php:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pageUrl);
$dom->getElementById(eleId);
```

How can you hide the element. I know how you can do it with css and js. But I want to know it with php.

Comment: The only way to hide an element from someone accessing it like that is to not have it in the DOM at all. When you hide it using CSS and JS, all it's really doing is adding styling to it for the browser so it knows if it should be displayed or not. It will still exist in the DOM and you can still see it if you do: "view source", unless your JS actually deletes the element from the DOM.

Comment: To `hide` it with PHP?? You can manipulate &/or delete with PHP but hide? You need to enable `output buffering` to do this with `live` html ~ probably using a custom callback function in conjunction with `ob_start` - this will allow you to modify and or delete

Comment: When you say “hide” an element, do you mean have it initially hidden when the document is rendered, or have the browser hide the element *after* it’s rendered and the page has been served?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m going to assume that you’re trying to have the element initially hidden i.e. in existence, but not visible, upon the browser’s initial rendering and you already know that PHP can’t directly instruct the browser to hide elements.

Following your example, you could do:

```
$eleId = “div_to_hide”;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($pageUrl);
$target_elem = $dom->getElementById($eleId);
if ($target_elem) {
    $target_elem-> setAttribute('style','display: none;');
}
```

Or you could create a “script” element containing JavaScript code to execute after the resource has totally downloaded to hide it at run-time.

Or you could create a “style” element in your DOMDocument object in which you’d put CSS content referencing the target element (by selector) to apply initial “display: none;” CSS.

Just other ideas, but the snippet above follows your paradigm.

Comment: Thank you Justin Jack, setAttribute I was looking for. Damn, sometimes you can't find the simplest things :)